# (amCharts) How to put multiple (two) data sets in one chart, and differentiate each data sets with different color schemes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to make a chart from two data sets. Both data are taken from two tables in the HTML.

With the code I currently have, the two tables are combined into only *one* data set. I want to separate each table to its own data set, because:

- I want to make each data set has its own color. E.g. data from table A will all be colored orange; data from table B will all be colored blue.
- The difference between each data will be from its line style. Data 1 will have thicker line, Data 2 will have dotted line, etc.

Here is the chart I intend to make.

[image]

Here is my current code and its result: http://jsfiddle.net/3j3s1ba7/4/

These are the lines where I get the data from the table

```
        function generateChartData() {

          // initialize empty array
          chartData = [];

          // get the table
          var table = document.getElementById( 'dataTable' );

          // get table rows
          var rows = table.getElementsByTagName( 'tr' );

          // iterate through the <td> elements of the first row
          // and construct chart data out of other rows as well
          var years = rows[ 0 ].getElementsByTagName( 'th' );
          var row1_desc = rows[ 1 ].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
          var row2_desc = rows[ 2 ].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
          var row3_desc = rows[ 3 ].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );

          var row
          for ( var x = 0; x < years.length; x++ ) {
            chartData.push( {
              "year": years[ x ].innerHTML,
              "row1_desc": row1_desc[ x ].innerHTML,
              "row2_desc": row2_desc[ x ].innerHTML,
              "row3_desc": row3_desc[ x ].innerHTML
            } );
          }
        }
```

In amCharts docs it is explained it is [possible to have two data sets, but it seems not at once](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/multiple-data-sets-with-regular-charts/).

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to have "seperate dataSets". DataSets are really a Stock Chart feature, not a Serial Chart feature.

In your function `generateGraphsFromData` you can simply add color and style settings to your graphs. You could give the graphs from Table 1 a different style than graphs from Table 2. You just have to find a way to tell the function which graph comes from which table.

Have a look at dashLength and lineColor settings: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph.

```
var graph_color = "orange"; // or blue
var graph_dashLength = 2;

var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.title = valueField;
graph.lineColor = graph_color,
graph.dashLength = graph_dashLength
// ...
```

Comment: Well I guess that's where I'm stuck: how to tell the function which graph comes from which table?